# Dynamically retrieve variable and argument values for NativeActivity

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I run the below code (C#) as a custom activity (compiled .dll is added to a nuget package and triggered in a UiPath sequence with some user defined variables/arguments. I am able to retrieve the name of the variable and it's type, but I cannot find the proper syntax to retrieve the value (I just want to convert it to a String, no need to do anything fancy). I can access some of the properties, so i know i am close. I have done my best to read the docs, but in this instance, it may be a little two abstract for me. I have gone through many interations and scoured as much of the internet as I can, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Hosting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;

namespace AutoLog
{
    public sealed class GetRootActivity : NativeActivity
    {
        public OutArgument<string> variables { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {

            this.variables.Set((ActivityContext)context, Library.getLocalVariables(context));
        }

        protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
        {
            base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
            metadata.AddDefaultExtensionProvider<GetRootActivity.WorkflowInstanceInfo>((Func<GetRootActivity.WorkflowInstanceInfo>)(() => new GetRootActivity.WorkflowInstanceInfo()));
        }

        public class Library
        {
            public static string getLocalVariables(NativeActivityContext context)
            {
                var properties = context.DataContext.GetProperties();
                JArray variables = new JArray();
                foreach(PropertyDescriptor p in properties)
                {
                    JObject variable = new JObject();
                    variable["name"] = p.Name;
                    variable["type"] = p.PropertyType.ToString();
                    string string_value = "";
                    try
                    {
                        var myValue = context.DataContext.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(context.DataContext, null);
                        string_value = myValue.ToString();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                    variable["value"] = string_value;
                    variables.Add(variable);
                }

                return variables.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is an example of the JSON it generates, as you can see, the "value" field is empty

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "type": "System.String",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "type": "System.Boolean",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "c",
    "type": "System.Int32",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
   "name": "test",
    "type": "System.String",
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "f",
    "type": "System.String",
    "value": ""
  }
]
```

Comment: Is the code within the try failing, hence `string_value` is never set. Could you add the line `string_value = "failed";` within the catch. That way it will identify if the code is failing.

Comment: Yes, the code within the block is failing. See my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myValue = context.DataContext.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(context.DataContext, null);
string_value = myValue.ToString();
```

can be changed to

```
string_value = p.GetValue(context.DataContext) as String;
```

I had previously tried this approach but got trying to make the cast dynamic, and apparently I had never tried the simpler solution.